# Navigating from landing page to create checkout session: The `price` parameter should be the ID of a price object, rather than the numerical price

Tags: python, html, stripe-payments

I am trying to navigate from my landing view to create checkout session view.
views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.views import View
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
import stripe
from .models import Product, Price

stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
# Create your views here.

class ProductLandingPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "landing.html"

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    product = Product.objects.get(name="Test Product")
    prices = Price.objects.filter(product=product)
    context = super(ProductLandingPageView,
                    self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context.update({
        "product": product,
        "prices": prices
    })
    return context  


class CreateCheckoutSessionView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        price = Price.objects.get(id=self.kwargs["pk"])
        YOUR_DOMAIN = "http://127.0.0.1:8000"  # change in production
        checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
            payment_method_types=['card'],
            line_items=[
            {
                'price': price.stripe_price_id,
                'quantity': 1,
            },
            ],
            mode='payment',
            success_url=YOUR_DOMAIN + '/success/',
            cancel_url=YOUR_DOMAIN + '/cancel/',
        )
        return redirect(checkout_session.url)
```

in models I have:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    stripe_product_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Price(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stripe_price_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)  # cents

    def get_display_price(self):
        return "{0:.2f}".format(self.price / 100)
```

in urls.py I have:

```
path('', ProductLandingPageView.as_view(), name='landing-page'),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('cancel/', CancelView.as_view(), name='cancel'),
path('success/', SuccessView.as_view(), name='success'),
path('create-checkout-session/<pk>/', CreateCheckoutSessionView.as_view(), name='create-checkout-session')
```

in admin I have:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Product, Price
# Register your models here.


class PriceInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Price
    extra = 0


class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PriceInlineAdmin]

admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

and in landing.html I have:

```
<body>
<section>
    <div class="product">
        <div class="description">
            <h3>{{ product.name }}</h3>
            <hr />
            {% for price in prices %}

            <div>
                <h5>${{ price.get_display_price }}</h5>
                <form action="{% url 'create-checkout-session' price.id %}" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <button type="submit">Checkout</button>
                </form>
            </div>

            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I ran makemigrations and migrate before runserver and the landing page works, but I get the following error:

> Request req_mqpyY9372O7on2: The `price` parameter should be the ID of
> a price object, rather than the literal numerical price.

Answer (score 0):

The error you shared means there is an issue with this part of the code:

```py
checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
  payment_method_types=['card'],
  line_items=[{
    'price': price.stripe_price_id,
    'quantity': 1,
  }],
  mode='payment',
  success_url=YOUR_DOMAIN + '/success/',
  cancel_url=YOUR_DOMAIN + '/cancel/',
)
```

Here, the value of the [`line_items .price`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-price) attribute should be a price ID, it's a string that looks like this: `price_xxx`. But based on the error message it seems that you are instead using an integer. So can you double check the value of the `price.stripe_price_id` variable and make sure it's a price ID?

Note that if you don't want to use a price ID, you could use [`line_items.price_data.unit_amount`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-price_data-unit_amount) instead.